# Python Модуль sys, ошибка при запуске IndexError: list index out of range

Tags: python, python-3.x, консоль

```
from datetime import datetime

import requests

API_KEY = "..."


def convert_currency(src, dst, amount):
    """converts `amount` from the `src` currency to `dst` using the free account"""
    url = f"http://data.fixer.io/api/latest?access_key={API_KEY}&symbols={src},{dst}&format=1"
    data = requests.get(url).json()
    if data["success"]:
        # request successful
        rates = data["rates"]
        # since we have the rate for our currency to src and dst, we can get exchange rate between both
        # using below calculation
        exchange_rate = 1 / rates[src] * rates[dst]
        last_updated_datetime = datetime.fromtimestamp(data["timestamp"])
        return last_updated_datetime, exchange_rate * amount


    if __name__ == "__main__":
      import sys

    source_currency = sys.argv[1]
    destination_currency = sys.argv[2]
    amount = float(sys.argv[3])

    last_updated_datetime, exchange_rate = convert_currency(source_currency, destination_currency, amount)
    # upgraded account, uncomment if you have one
    # last_updated_datetime, exchange_rate = convert_currency source_currency, destination_currency, amount)
    print("Last updated datetime:", last_updated_datetime)
    print(f"{amount} {source_currency} = {exchange_rate} {destination_currency}")
```

Всем привет. Пытался разобраться с модулем sys, чтобы сделать CLI интерфейс, но при запуске выдает ошибку. Не подскажите в чем именно проблема? Заранее спасибо.

```
source_currency = sys.argv[1]
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Comment: а откуда в `sys.argv` должны взяться значения? Вставьте `print(sys.argv)` и посмотрите, что там внутри.

Comment: @Сергей ['/Users/nikolay/Desktop/Basic/L6/example.py'] - выдает путь к модулю. Я просто думал что sys, позволяет вводить аргументы через консоль. Если я конечно же правильно понял его работу.

Comment: <https://python-scripts.com/module-sys> - на всякий случай

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема в том, что вы неправильно вызываете свое приложение.

`sys.argv` содержит параметры, которые вы передали в командной строке своему приложению. То есть, если запускаете приложение командой:

```
python app.py 1 2 3
```

то в `sys.argv` будет список `['app.py', '1', '2', '3']`. `index out of range` в общем означает, что элемента с таким индексом в списке нет. В вашем же случае это означает, что вы не передали параметры в командной строке, как того ожидает этот код.

Чтоб исправить просто передайте нужные параметры при запуске.